# forming clusters/groups in a dataset based on unique values from some of the columns using R

Tags: r, dplyr, cluster-analysis, hierarchical-clustering

I have a following dataset, this is a sample dataset which depicts the Products and its features(in each columns). It contains 12 features/columns for the 21 Products/records.

```
Data.df <- structure(list(Product.group = c("A Box", "A Box", "A Box", "A Box", 
"A Box", "A Box", "A Box", "A Box", "B Box", "B Box", "B Box", 
"B Box", "B Box", "B Box", "B Box", "B Box", "C Box", "C Box", 
"C Box", "C Box", "C Box"), Performance = c("High", "High", "High", 
"Medium", "Medium", "Low", "Low", "Low", "High", "High", "High", 
"High", "Low", "Low", "Low", "Medium", "High", "High", "Low", 
"Low", "Low"), Family = c("A1", "A1", "A1", "A1", "A1", "A2", 
"A2", "A2", "B1", "B1", "B1", "B1", "B1", "B2", "B2", "B1", "C1", 
"C2", "C1", "C1", "C2"), Product.ID = c("A111", "A112", "A113", 
"A114", "A118", "A211", "A222", "A347", "AX12", "AX14", "AX16", 
"AX18", "AY78", "AY89", "AY91", "B122", "AA11", "AA32", "AA43", 
"AC21", "AC43"), Function = c("ELEC", "ELEC", "ELEC", "ELEC", 
"ELEC", "ELEC", "ELEC", "ELEC", "ELEC", "ELEC", "GAS", "GAS", 
"ELEC", "ELEC", "ELEC", "ELEC", "GAS", "GAS", "GAS", "GAS", "GAS"
), Voltage = c("G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", 
"G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G"), Gas.stage = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "A112", "A112", NA, NA, NA, 
NA, "A150", "A150", "A240", "A240", "A240"), Electric = c(NA, 
NA, "22KW", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "22KW", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "7.5KW", 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), Drive = c("Direct", "Direct", "Direct", 
"Direct", "Direct", "Direct", "Direct", "Direct", "Direct", "Direct", 
"Direct", "Direct", "Direct", "Direct", "Direct", "Direct", "Direct", 
"Direct", "Direct", "Direct", "Direct"), Exhaust = c(NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, "Single", NA, NA, NA, NA, "Single", NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, "Single", NA, NA, "Double", "Double"), Fuse = c("15A", "15A", 
"15A", "15A", "15A", "15A", "15A", "15A", "15A", "15A", "15A", 
"15A", "15A", "15A", "15A", "15A", "15A", "15A", "20A", NA, "15A"
), Accessory = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "Installed", NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "Installed", NA)), row.names = c(NA, 
21L), class = "data.frame")
```

Is there a way to subset this dataset into multiple groups based on unique values from some of the columns/features. The columns that are used for grouping are

1. Product group
2. Performance
3. Family
4. Function
5. Voltage

Need to subset the entire data based on unique values from these columns in the same order mentioned as above and give this subset an unique group id.

I have just started learning about clustering and it would be of great help if anyone could advise on this.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

We can use `group_indices` from the `dplyr` package

```
library(dplyr)

#group by columns of interest, create group ID
Data.df <- Data.df %>% group_by(Product.group, Performance, Family, Function, Voltage) %>% mutate(groupid = group_indices())

#split by group_indice (list of subsets)
split(Data.df, Data.df$groupid)
```

Comment: But i want the group index to be available on the original data set after the subset is done. Is that possible

Comment: Adjusted code accordingly. Assuming you want to subset based on the unique levels of the column combination